# Inserir botão de como chegar num mapa

Tags: google-maps, geolocalização

preciso inserir um botão no meu site para que ao clicar uma rota seja estabelecida pegando a localização do cliente até o endereço que já estará estabelecido na página do site.

Aqui vai a página com o mapa e o local que a pessoa pode querer visitar. 
http://pousadadasrosas.com/pdr-local.php?ponto_turistico=centro-de-miguel-pereira

Obrigado!

Comment: Vicius Soares, tudo bom? Pode especificar melhor o seu problema? O que você tentou até agora? Colocar o código pode ajudar o pessoal a responder sua pergunta.

Comment: Olá, Asura, td bem? Eu preciso que o site faça o que o app do gmaps faz no celular: qd vc acessa o aplicativo ele pega sua localização e pede para que vc coloque o endereço para onde quer ir. Daí ele traça uma rota. No caso do site o destino já estará escolhido, preciso pegar a localização do cliente para criar a rota.

Answer (score 1):

Se você usa HTML5 no seu código, é uma tarefa bem simples que você precisa executar.

Antes de mais nada, é necessário obter a localização da empresa. Ela será facilmente obtido através da seguinte função:

```js
function addEmpresaMarker(latitude, longitude, marcadorEmp) {
  var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
  marcadorEmp = new google.maps.Marker {
    map: map,
    position: coords
  };
}
```

Em seguida, você precisa saber a localização do seu usuário. Existe uma função do HTML5 que permite que você saiba a localização do usuário (Use com moderação). Execute-a e já adicione as coordenadas num novo marcador. Segue função abaixo.

```js
function findUserLocation(marcadorUsu) {
  // Mapa e opções do mapa já estão definidos previamente
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var posicao = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };
      console.log(posicao); // Confira se a localização está correta
      marcadorUsu = new google.maps.Marker {
        map: map,
        position: posicao
      };
    });
  } else {
    // Browser não suporta Geolocalização ou o usuário impediu o uso
    alert('Falha na tentativa de localização do usuário');
  }
}
```

Agora, você precisa calcular a rota entre o usuário e a empresa. Para isso, você vai precisar da Google Maps Directions API, que irá calcular distância e mostrar a rota, obviamente. Note que, para calcular a rota, ele precisa de referências dos marcadores de origem e destino. Observe bem a função:

```js
function mostrarCaminho (pointA, pointB) {
  // Aciona a Directions API
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
      map: mapa,
      suppressMarkers: true, // Não exibe os marcadores da rota, porque senão, pode confundir o usuário
  });
  directionsService.route({
    origin: pointA,
    destination: pointB,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) { // Se deu tudo certo
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    } else {
      window.alert('Não foi possível exibir o trajeto devido ao seguinte erro: ' + status);
    }
  });
}
```

Agora é só juntar os comandos que você criou numa única função que será executada quando o botão 'Como chegar' for clicado. A função deve ficar mais ou menos assim:

```js
// AddEmpresaMarker()

var coordsEmp = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
marcadorEmp = new google.maps.Marker {
  map: map,
  position: coordsEmp
};

// FindUserLocation()
// Mapa e opções do mapa já estão definidos previamente

if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    var posicao = {
      lat: position.coords.latitude,
      lng: position.coords.longitude
    };
    console.log(posicao); // Confira se a localização está correta
    marcadorUsu = new google.maps.Marker {
      map: map,
      position: posicao
    };
  });
} else {
  // Browser não suporta Geolocalização ou o usuário impediu o uso
  return alert('Falha na tentativa de localização do usuário'); // Esse return é pra finalizar a função. De nada adianta executar toda a função se você não tem uma das posições
}

// MostrarCaminho()
// Aciona a Directions API

var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
  map: mapa,
  suppressMarkers: true, // Não exibe os marcadores da rota, porque senão, pode confundir o usuário
});
directionsService.route({
  origin: pointA,
  destination: pointB,
  travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
}, function(response, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) { // Se deu tudo certo
    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
  } else {
    alert('Não foi possível exibir o trajeto devido ao seguinte erro: ' + status);
  }
});
```

Pode ser que tenha algum erro de sintaxe aí no meio, mas é bem tranquilo corrigir.
Qualquer dúvida, comente. Eu vou deixar alguns links que podem te ajudar nesse processo:

Marcadores: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers?hl=pt-br

Localização do usuário: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp

Rotas: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro?hl=pt-br

Answer (score -1):

Cara é uma gambiarra, mas funciona.

Eu copiei o link que está no botão e alterei o destino:

```html
<a href="http://maps.google.com/?saddr=Current%20Location&daddr=ENDEREÇO AQUI" target="_blank">COMO CHEGAR</a>
```

É exatamente o que o cliente quer, é uma gambiarra mas funciona